# DynamoDBStorageHandler Hive connector

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

when I run this command from Hive shell in our EMR cluster:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_db.my_table
     (col1 string, ...)
 STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
 TBLPROPERTIES (
     "dynamodb.table.name" = "table_name", 
     "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "col1:col1  ... "
 );
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException Call From ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal/xx.xx.xx.xxx to ip-yy-yy-yy-yyy.ec2.internal:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=ip-yy-yy-yy-yyy.ec2.internal/yy.yy.yy.yyy:8020]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout)
```

The EMR cluster is in VPC.
I Tried editing the Inbound/Outbound rules of the security group of the master node, so far with no success.

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 0):

AWS Support were able to assist me: the problem was that the database location in Glue was pointing to old HDFS address ip-yy-yy-yy-yyy.ec2.internal (different then xx.xx.xx.xxx), according to the master's node of the previous cluster. I changed to location to point to S3 and the problem was resolved.